# searching for searchers on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, app-engine-ndb

my search problem is the following.

My site has job offers, and we have users (searchers) that are interested in getting notified if new offers arrive. The users set some keywords for their jobsearch which change very unfrequently. There are new job offers on a frequent basis (about 100 new offers every day). And the number of users could get to be highish (hopefully), in the order of 10K-100K users, although now it is much more modest.

Initially, I approached the problem by periodically doing each user's search and filtering for new offers. I find this to be very inefficient, but it works as long as the number of users is small. However, I should start thinking about an alternative way to do this for a larger number of users.

So, what I would like to do, but I don't know if it is possible nor even **how this type of searching is called**, is the following. Although the number of users should grow large, the number of new offers per day will not. So, when a new job offer arrives, **I would like to be able to search users whose query matches this job offer**, obviously without having to run each user's query.

I'm thinking of something like indexing my users queries and search on that, but I don't know how to break up the job offer in a way that I can use to feed that search.

I am doing this on appengine-python, so the options I have are somehow limited by the platform.

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Well, currently I'm doing the search running each user's query one by one, but I have to do too many searches. I am thinking about this alternative option, but I have not been able to manage out anything that I could actually try. That's the point of this question, to see if someone could shed some light on any resources that I could follow. Just knowing what to google for would be of great help, I have googled for things like "inverse search", I have looked for search algorithms that could somehow resemble what I'm looking for, but I haven't found anything similar.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to your question. Please also describe the concret problems you have: what works, what doesn't, what do you expect, was is the acutal result. Then we will perhaps be able to help you.

Comment: @Tichodroma Not every question on SO relates to existing code. This is one that clearly doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and for your friendly answer, Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called Prospective Search (as opposed to the more common Retrospective Search), and Google App Engine has [an API for exactly that](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/).